# Python 3 - Get definition path of object

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my main file of my Python3 project, I want to display dotted definition path of imported class as string.

**My imported class:**

Is named `WoodCuting` and is located in `constants/dimensions.py`.

```
class WoodCuting():
    WIDTH = 12
    HEIGHT = 12
```

**What I want:**

Dotted definition path of imported class as a string - `constants.dimensions.WoodCuting`.

**What I tried:**

`str(type(WoodCuting))` returns `constants.dimensions.WoodCuting` - which is exactly what I want. However it is not reliable solution.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with the object's `__module__` and [`__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name) attributes.

```
>>> '.'.join((WoodCuting.__module__, WoodCuting.__qualname__))
'constants.dimensions.WoodCuting'
```

Using `__qualname__` rather than `__name__` means you get the correct result for nested objects.

Say this class is in the module:

```
class Foo:
    class Bar:
        pass

>>> '.'.join((constants.dimensions.Foo.Bar.__module__, constants.dimensions.Foo.Bar.__qualname__))
'constants.dimensions.Foo.Bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import inspect

class WoodCuting():
    WIDTH = 12
    HEIGHT = 12

a=inspect.getfile(WoodCuting)
print (a)
```

Comment: This returns `/constants/dimensions.py` instead `constants.dimensions.WoodCuting`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `WoodCuting` is located in `constants/dimensions.py`:

```
from constants.dimensions import WoodCuting

def get_full_name(c):
    return c.__class__.__module__ + '.' + c.__class__.__name__

print(get_full_name(WoodCuting()))
```

returns `constants.dimensions.WoodCuting`.